# Flutter Dio multipart image, Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: flutter, dart, multipartform-data, dio, multipartfile

I am trying to send multiple images to the backend server.
I have tried Dio and Http but the server responds with an error and the rest of the data except the images get saved.

The documentation says that the key values must be **'images_0' 'images_1'** and so on.

**Code -**

The images are converted from XFile to multipart file.

```
int imgNum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++) {
    if (data.images[i] != null) {
      File file = File(data.images[i]!.path);     
      String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

      http.MultipartFile mFile = http.MultipartFile(
        'images_$imgNum', 
        file.readAsBytes().asStream(), 
        await file.length(),        
        filename: fileName,
      );
      imgNum++;
      request.files.add(mFile);
    }
  }
```

(data.images is a list of XFiles? , request is the http.MultipartRequest)

All the other fields and headers are working and being saved correctly.
I have tried using Dio too which gives the same response. The response from the server is :

> {data: {error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined}, message: Something went wrong. Please try again later.}

Our project also has a website where the form is working correctly, and when the http request there shows the images as follows : (in Google Chrome)

[Under form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27fkk.png)

[Form Data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJWXh.png)

The api team has also shared Swagger Ui API docs-
[Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4IyF.png)

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thank you for responding.

Comment: Your `images` array seems empty

Comment: @gtxtreme no,  i have checked it using print statements.